# Android accessibility: How to get the ID of the view that was touched?

Tags: android, accessibility, accessibilityservice

I have been stuck on this for days. I want to identify the view that the user touches. Here is my accessibility service xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<accessibility-service
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeViewClicked"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackGeneric"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews|flagRetrieveInteractiveWindows|flagReportViewIds"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description_3"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

And the service:

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();

    AccessibilityServiceInfo configuration = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
    configuration.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED;
    configuration.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;

    configuration.flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_INCLUDE_NOT_IMPORTANT_VIEWS
            | AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS
            | AccessibilityServiceInfo.FLAG_RETRIEVE_INTERACTIVE_WINDOWS;

    setServiceInfo(configuration);
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {

    if (event.getEventType() == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED) {

        //Toast to show the id of the view that was clicked
        Toast.makeText(this, "" + event.getWindowId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

`event.getWindowId()` is not working. I'm not sure whose ID it's giving but it gives the same ID for any view inside an app. I want the ID of the view that the user touched.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
    event.source.viewIdResourceName
    // or
    findFocusedViewInfo().viewIdResourceName
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#getViewIdResourceName()):

> Gets the fully qualified resource name of the source view's id.
> Note: The primary usage of this API is for UI test automation and in order to report the source view id of an AccessibilityNodeInfo the client has to set the AccessibilityServiceInfo#FLAG_REPORT_VIEW_IDS flag when configuring the AccessibilityService.